# Smoothness in formal GAGA

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, formal-schemes

Suppose $X$ is a noetherian scheme over a complete noetherian local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m})$, and assume $X$ is projective.

If $\widehat{X}$, the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic formal completion, is smooth in the sense of formal schemes, that is, Zariski locally on $\widehat{X}$, there is an étale map to a formal affine space, is $X$ smooth over $A$?

Comment: The non-smooth locus of $X$ is closed, so if it is non-empty it has to meet the special fiber because $X$ is proper.

Comment: (And if $X$ is not proper then then the statement is false, for example the plane curve $y^2 = (tx-1)^3$ over $k[[t]]$ is singular but its central fiber $y^2 = -1$ is smooth, and hence so is the $t$-adic completion).